# Redirecting python output to file prints two lines

Tags: python, logging

Using the advice of another stack overflow question I wrote my own LogWriter class:

```
class LogWriter:
    def __init__(self, output, filename):
            self.output = output
            self.logfile = file(filename, 'a')

    def write(self, text):
            now = datetime.now()
            stamp = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d - %I:%M:%S")
            text = "[%s] %s" % (stamp,text)
            if(DEBUG):
                    self.output.write(text)
                    self.output.flush()
            self.logfile.write(text)
            self.logfile.flush()

    def close(self):
            self.output.close()
            self.logfile.close()
```

However this is the output I recieve:

```
    >>logwriter = LogWriter(sys.stdout, LOG_FILENAME)
    >>sys.stdout = logwriter
    >>print "test"
    [2011-12-12 - 08:15:00] test[2011-12-12 - 08:15:00]
```

If i remove the line that modifies text and print just the original message, the class works as expected, printing to both the log file and stdout:

```
test
```

For some reason my timestamp is duplicated, and I can't figure out why. What is the proper way to fix this error in python?

**EDIT:** As aix has said below, I was making an assumption that print calls and write calls were one-to-one, but this isn't true. As a simple fix to continue using my LogWriter class I am now making the calls as follows:

```
...
def write(self, text):
            now = datetime.now()
            stamp = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d - %I:%M:%S")
            text = "[%s] %s\n" % (stamp,text)
...
>>logwriter = LogWriter(sys.stdout, LOG_FILENAME)
>>logwriter.write("test")
[2011-12-12 - 08:38:55] test
```

Comment: I would really recommend http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html

Comment: This is overkill for what I need to do, I will only be making 4-5 log calls, but I thought this was a pythonic way to do logging, it turns out I was wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be assuming that a single `print` statement results in a single call to `write()`. Therefore I believe that the whole approach of producing a timestamp on every `write()` is flawed.

You could try to fix this by producing a timestamp at the start of each *line* (by looking for `\n` characters in `text`), but that doesn't strike me as being particularly elegant either.

Comment: You're right. I had previously assumed that a multi-line print still results in a single call to write. It appears that the break was occuring on a newline, so I was getting the 'test' and '\n' separately. I am going to abandon this approach.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
>>>print "test",
```

Possibly you are getting the implicit newline from `print` as a separate call to `write()`.  Either way, the problem is that you're getting multiple calls to `write()` (as there is no guarantee how a caller uses `write()` - it could call it for every character if it liked).

Comment: No such luck, still results in the same print statement as above.